# Error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘TR’

Tags: c, bison

I have a problem defining my structure inside the union on Bison

I made a structure

```
typedef enum {Binary_Op,Uni_Op,Variable, Const} Tag_Type;

typedef struct tree
{
    Tag_Type Tag;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            char op;
            struct tree *left, *right;
        }bin_op;

        struct
        {
            char op;
            struct tree *arg; /* negative or positive */
        }uni_op;

        char var;
        int const_val;
    }u;

}TREE_REC, *TR;




%}

%union
{

    int y_int;
    TR y_tree;
}

%type <y_tree> expr term factor assign
%token <y_int> CONST
%token <y_int> VAR



%%
```

but inside the union TR has an error. I don't understand why!! any help?

Comment: Can you provide the error message please?

Comment: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘TR’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with your `typedef struct tree {...} TREE_REC, *TR`. I would have rather written :

```
typedef struct tree {...} TREE_REC; //Alias on struct tree 
typedef TREE_REC * TR; //Definition of the pointer to a struct tree
```

The `,` in your typedef is disturbing me.

Can you test my solution, or just clarify the syntax of your typedef?

Comment: The first argument is literally the list and then the second argument in the struct gives us the pointer to the nodes of the tree.

Comment: Right! Great! You should look to close the question then.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `struct tree` and `TR` in a header file that you `#include` before you `#include "y.tab.h"`.  The error message is telling you that you're trying to use `TR` before the compiler has seen a definition for it.

Comment: I personally got this error because I forgot to define my enum as typedef. This answer triggered my memory :)